# What live linux smaller 2GB and with pre-installed `wpa_supplicant` is suited best for Gentoo installation?

Tags: gentoo, live-usb, livecd, wpa-supplicant, wlan

I have a mid-old laptop that I want to use for learning more details about Linux, so I decided for a first-time Gentoo installation. I can only connect via WLAN to internet with this laptop. My router only supports WPA(2). My biggest USB stick has 2GB for the live linux, so the full Gentoo live DVD (larger than 2GB) is no option. The minimalist Gentoo has no `wpa_supplicant` (which would be needed for WPA), however.

What is the best option for me to follow the Gentoo manual as closely as possible?

Comment: Do you have a linux installed on your laptop?

Comment: No, it's a clean drive.

Comment: Do you have any linux experience? If so, what distro do you have used already?

Comment: Yes, I have some experience. Most experience I have with a SSH-controlled Debian/Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi. And also some Ubuntu experience. So, I'm not a total newbie, just with low level installing. And I have absolutely no overview of the huge "distro database".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Just Download a Live-Distro of your choice (with wpa_supplicant) with the same arch (32/64 bit) you'll choose for gentoo later, too
2. Create a bootable USB-Stick from it
3. Boot from the USB-Stick
4. Most of the upcomping steps require root privileges, so you could do a `su` in your Live-Distro and go on as root.
5. Create your partitions (/boot,/home/,/) e.g. with [fdisk](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html) on the hdd of the laptop
6. Create FileSystem with:
   `mkfs.ext2 /dev/WHATEVER_YOUR_BOOT_IS`,
   `mkfs.ext4 /dev/WHATEVER_YOUR_HOME_IS`
   and
   `mkfs.ext4 /dev/WHATEVER_YOUR_ROOT_IS`
7. `mkdir /mnt/gentoo`
8. Mount `/`-partition to `/mnt/gentoo` with:
   `mount /dev/WHATEVER_YOUR_ROOT_IS /mnt/gentoo`
9. Create directories for mounting `/home` and `/boot` with:
   `mkdir /mnt/gentoo/{boot,home}`
10. Mount `/home` and `/boot` with:
    `mount /dev/WHATEVER_YOUR_BOOT_IS /mnt/gentoo/boot`
    and
    `mount /dev/WHATEVER_YOUR_HOME_IS /mnt/gentoo/home`
11. Download stage3 gentoo [32](http://distfiles.gentoo.org/releases/x86/autobuilds/current-stage3-i686/)/[64](http://distfiles.gentoo.org/releases/amd64/autobuilds/current-stage3-amd64/) bit (not hardened for now) to the User directory of your live-system
12. In the directory of the stage3:
    `tar -C /mnt/gentoo -xjf stage3.....tar.bz2` (that could take a moment)
13. Now [chroot into your new gentoo](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Chroot)
14. Install [wpa_supplicant](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=4&chap=4) and [bootloater](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-amd64.xml?part=1&chap=10)
15. Shutdown Live-USB, unplug USB-Stick, reboot

Now you should be able to boot into your gentoo (i hope i didn't missed anything :>)

Comment: Thank you very much. :) The Gentoo manual sounded like there'll be unneccessary problems if one takes a live linux that is not "supported" in the manual, but you proved this wrong. :)

Comment: Did everything run flawless, or is anything wrong/missleading/not-working/missing, that i need to adapt/add?

Comment: Yes, everything went fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

systemresquecd is a gentoo-based live-cd with wpa_supplicant, you can find it [here](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage)